# Django: List items in database not displaying on the html template

Tags: django, database, templates, view, rendering

As part of a Django project, I have the following code (html template) and views.py file, but the items that are in the database are not being displayed in the browser when I run the server. It simply displays an empty list with **three items** in it.

I definitely have at least **three items** in the database as shown below:

```
>>> from worldguestbook.models import GuestBookItem
>>> GuestBookItem.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<GuestBookItem: GuestBookItem object (1)>, <GuestBookItem: GuestBookItem object (2)>, <GuestBookItem: GuestBookItem object (3)>]>
>>>
```

**html file code** (this shows the bottom part of the html template code. Could the error be in the way the html is arranged?)

```
       <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
            <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
            <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="" style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;"><input type="text" name="b_410ed4e009d15301d90f6492b_753384883a" value=""></div>
        </form>
        <span class="form_nospam">Warning: The world will see your message</span>
      </div>
      <!--End mc_embed_signup-->
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /end of Row-->
</div>
<!-- End of container-->
<ul>
    {% for guestbookitem in all_items %}
        <li> {{ GuestBookItem.content }} </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**views.py code**

```
from django.shortcuts import render 

from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import GuestBookItem


# Create your views here.
def worldguestbookView(request):
    allguestbookitems=GuestBookItem.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'worldguestbook\worldguestbook.html',{'all_items' : allguestbookitems})

def loginView(request):
    return render(request, 'worldguestbook\login.html')
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class GuestBookItem(models.Model):
    content=models.TextField()
```

Note: The server does not throw any exceptions/errors on running, so I have found it difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: Try `{{ guestbookitem.content }}` (Django variables are case-sensitive).

Comment: @EndreBoth  - worked! Thank you!

Comment: From the line above it: `for guestbookitem...`.

Comment: Not related, but you should use forward slashes in your template paths: `'worldguestbook/worldguestbook.html'`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - can you explain why? This seems to work....and forward slash, if I remember right, somehow caused an error.

Comment: Because a backslash means an escape code. If your template was called "name.html", for example, then "worldguestbook\name.html" would be interpreted as "worldguestbook<newline>ame.html".

Answer (score 1):

May you should replace `<li> {{ GuestBookItem.content }} </li>` into `<li> {{ guestbookitem.content }} </li>`